# Polymer-TS Generate Doc

Tags: typescript, polymer

I am using Polymer-TS (https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS) to implement web-components and I can't find any solution to generate documentation for my classes.

I tried to use iron-elements (iron-component-page), which uses Hydrolysis (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-analyzer). But it is not compatible with Typescript (only Polymer) - at the moment.

So has anybody already found solution or is making his own?

Of course solutions like JSDoc etc. are still in play, but I am looking for more sophisticated one.

Thank You